# Where to use converters?

Tags: json, android-annotations

I've just installed [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) and I want to use the `@Rest` annotation, however, as I read:

> You MUST define converters field on this @Rest annotation, which
>   corresponds to the Spring HttpMessageConverters that will be provided
>   to the RestTemplate.

So, where to get `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`? and how to install it?

Or at least, to convert my expected json string into a json object?
Is there any simple example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written in the [documentation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#introduction), you have to add the Spring REST template dependency, which is the underlying REST library, AA is just a wrapper around it.

You can do it by adding this to your `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
} repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

Now you can add any converter, like it is outlined in the [doc](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#converters):

```
@Rest(converters = { MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MyRestClient {
    @Get("/events")
    EventList getEvents();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I repeat the last rest call in-case of a retry attempt due to an error? is there a recommended pattern for this? so that we can minimize code redundancy

Comment: You can use OkHttp as the request factory which automatically retries requests.